# Zero homology and path-component

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I try to show the two next things :

> $H_{0}(X,A)=0$ iff $A$ meets each path-component of $X$

and

> $H_{1}(X,A)=0$ iff $H_{1}(A)\rightarrow H_{1}(X)$ is surjective and each path-component of $X$ contains at most one path-component of $A$.

Do I need to use only the definition of homology (the quotient $Ker(d_{n})/Im(d_{n+1})$) or I need something else ?

Thank you for answer !

Comment: General advice: it is almost always impossible to work directly from the definition of homology as $\ker d / \operatorname{im} d$. You need to work with the properties of homology you know, like functoriality, homotopy invariance, Mayer-Vietoris... Or in this case, the long exact sequence of a pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still new at this so grains of salt are still advised.

The second one looks like it may be aided by the long exact sequence of the pair:

$$H_1(A)\to H_1(X)\to H_1(X,A)\to H_0(A)\to H_0(X)$$

The fact that $X$ contains at most one path-component of $A$ per path component means that the last arrow is injective. We are given that the first arrow must be surjective; from these you can work out that the center homology is trivial. (The opposite direction is easy, unless I'm terribly mistaken)

The first part is definitely doable with the LESP, but it may be more hassle than it's worth, depending on what you're willing to assume or prove about path-connectedness.

Comment: Just extend the long exact sequence you wrote down on the right to include $\rightarrow H_0(X,A)\rightarrow 0$. From there you can conclude that $H_0(X,A)=0$ iff the map $H_0(A)\rightarrow H_0(X)$ is surjective.

Comment: @Michalis: I had thought about this but it wasn't obvious to me how that was equivalent to the path-component statement. But I think that was because I was tired; it looks pretty obvious now.

Comment: It's not completely obvious, one needs to know the structure of $H_0(X)$ which is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, one for every path component of $X$. The same is true for $H_0(A)$ and the map $H_0(A)\rightarrow H_0(X)$ maps a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to a pathconnected component $A_1$ of $A$ identically to the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to the pathconnected $X_1$ of $X$ that contains $A_1$. So if $A$ meets every path connected component it is surjective.